# Uncaught ReferenceError: AddLoginModalEvent is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, reactjs

I am using **django** and **reactjs** for developing my app. I am trying to create a login form with modal effect using **reactjs** and **semantic-ui** but I am getting an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: AddLoginModalEvent is not defined`.

My code

**base.html**

```
    <div class="ui large top fixed hidden menu navbar">
      <div class="ui container">
        <a class="active item"></a>
        <div class="ui buttons">
          <a class="ui button tomato pair" onClick="AddLoginModalEvent()">Login</a>
          <div class="or"></div>
          <a class="ui positive button pair">Signup</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 <div id="loginmodal"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/semantic.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'build/js/app.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      var data = {
             isUserAuthenticated:{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}true{% else %}false{% endif %}
        };

    $(function() {

      app.showLoginModal("loginmodal",data);
    });

</script>
```

**Index.js**
(entry: "./src/index.js",) its a entry point in webpack

```
import LoginModal from 'homepage/LoginModal';

window.app = {

    showLoginModal: function(id,data){
        ReactDOM.render(
          <LoginModal data={data} />, document.getElementById(id)
        );
    },
}
```

**LoginModal.js**

```
 function AddLoginModalEvent(){
    let event = document.createEvent('Event');
    event.initEvent('addLoginModal', true, true);
    document.dispatchEvent(event);
}

class LoginModal extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            showModal:'none'
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener('addLoginModal', (e) => {
            this.showModal();
        }, false);
        $('.ui.modal').modal({detachable: false});
    }

    showModal(){
        this.setState({ showModal:'inherit' });
         $('.ui.modal.editform').modal('show');
    }

    closeModal(){
        this.setState({ showModal:'none'});
    }

  render() {
    const style = { display:this.state.showModal, top:'50px' };
    const close = <div className="ui black deny button" onClick={this.closeModal}> Nope </div>;

    return (
          <div>
            <AddLoginModal style={style} title="Login" close={close} />
          </div>
      );
  }
}


class AddLoginModal extends Component{
    render(){
      return(
        <div style={this.props.style}>
            <div className="ui modal editform">
                <div className="ui middle aligned center aligned grid">
                  <div className="column">
                    <h2 className="ui teal image header">
                      <div className="content">
                        Log-in to your account
                      </div>
                    </h2>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     )
    }
}

export default LoginModal;
```

Where am i doing wrong?